# array of objects c++ pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is my quadTree.h file

```
class quadTree{
public :
Rectangle bounds;
quadTree *nodes[4];
int level;
char collision;

void split();
bool containsObstacle( vector<Rectangle> obstacles);

quadTree(int level, Rectangle bounds);
};
```

This is my quadTree.cpp file:

```
void quadTree:: split(){
int childWidth  = (int)( bounds.getWidth() / 2);
int childHeight = (int)(bounds.getHeight() / 2);

nodes[0] = new quadTree(level + 1 , Rectangle(bounds.getX()+childWidth ,
                                                            bounds.getY() , childWidth , childHeight));

nodes[1] = new quadTree(level + 1 , Rectangle(bounds.getX() , bounds.getY()+childHeight ,
                                                            childWidth , childHeight));

nodes[2] = new quadTree(level + 1 , Rectangle(bounds.getX()+childWidth , bounds.getY()+childHeight ,
                                                         childWidth , childHeight));

nodes[3] = new quadTree(level + 1, Rectangle(bounds.getX() , bounds.getY() , childWidth, childHeight));
}

quadTree::quadTree(int level , Rectangle bounds){
   this -> level = level;
   this -> bounds = bounds;
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

```
quadTree test (0,Rectangle(0,0,700,700));
test.split();
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
cout<<test.nodes[i]->bounds.getX()<<" "<<test.nodes[i]->bounds.getY();
}
```

But for some reason Xcode, keeps giving me 11db errors when I try to run this. My question is am I correctly storing the values into the array? I am fairly new to c++ and this is my first time using pointers.
Thanks

Comment: Could you paste your full code?

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces between a pointer and `->`.  `this -> bounds = bounds;` should be `this->bounds = bounds;`

Comment: I probably don't need them, but they are to ensure that I get an integer value back when I, for example, do 35/2.

Comment: Your code seems to run fine on the latest Clang. BTW, you seem to be referring to an [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/) error but I'm not using XCode. Can you give the actual error?

Comment: Everything seems OK here. Perhaps something is not right in `Rectangle`.

Comment: I'm having trouble with Xcode then I guess. I don't necessarily get an error, but I am getting no output from my cout statements. The Rectangle class is pretty straight forward. I just wanted to make sure that everything looked okay with my pointers. Thanks

Comment: @GuntherFox: Spaces are allowed here. It is so just a style issue.